# Merging files/namespaces/modules in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I feel like this has a simple answer, but I can't make sense of the documentation in relation to merging across multiple files.

```
// a.ts
enum Color{
    RED,
    BLUE
}
```

---

```
// b.ts
enum Day{
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY
}
```

---

```
// c.ts
import * as Types from "a, b";

console.log(Types.Color.RED, Types.Day.MONDAY);
```

---

I have enums in multiple files, but want them all to be usable through one identifier.  Obviously the comma notation in `c.ts` doesn't make any sense, so how can I achieve what the `console.log` is doing?

I've played around with namespaces and modules but haven't got anything syntactically correct yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got two options:

It is possible to merge declarations in different files, but only if they are pure declaration files, not modules.

You can do this:

a.d.ts:

```
declare enum A {
    a = 0,
    b,
}
```

b.d.ts:

```
declare enum A {
    c,
    d
}
```

test.ts:

```
const a = A.a;
const c = A.c;
```

This works because the `A` enumeration belongs to the global scope, so TypeScript merges them. It would also work with namespaces.

However, the moment you turn one of these files into a module, it'll stop working.

If you do at the end of b.d.ts:

```
export = A;
```

Now that file is exporting something: it's turned into a module, and everything declared inside that file belongs to the scope of the module.

Now, in test.ts, the line `const c = A.c` will indicate an error. The global enum `A` only has two values: `a` and `b`.

So, if your enum is declared in files that are modules (export something) then you can't mix those declarations.

In this case, you should add a definition file to your project (a `d.ts`) file, and define your enum in it, then it'll be globally available. In fact, this would be the best approach, so there is only one point to modify that enum. Merging declarations in different files are useful for namespaces, but don't really make much sense for enums:

a-enum.d.ts:

```
 declare enum A {
     a = 0,
     b,
     c,
     d,
 }
```